# Calculating the amount of full months between two dates?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

First and last dates of a time series are as follows:

```
firstday = transactions["Date"].head(1)
firstday
lastday = transactions["Date"].tail(1)
lastday

Dateindex
2017-12-30   2017-12-30
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
Dateindex
2018-12-31   2018-12-31
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I want the following two things:

1) get firstday and lastday as "2017-12-30" and "2018-12-31" (strings), instead of `dtype('<M8[ns]')`

2) calculate the number of **whole months** between these dates (correct output would be 12 months)

Any ideas how to achieve these? Thank you.

Comment: How do you define "whole" month?

Comment: Good question, the point is to count the amount of unique months in the series except for those in the beginning or the end with just one entry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Select first and last value by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html):

```
firstday = transactions["Date"].iat[0]
lastday = transactions["Date"].iat[-1]
```

Alternative is use [`Index.get_loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) for position for column `Date` with [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html):

```
firstday = transactions.iat[0, transactions.columns.get_loc('Date')]
lastday = transactions.iat[-1, transactions.columns.get_loc('Date')]
```

---

```
print (firstday)
2017-12-30 00:00:00

print (lastday)
2018-12-31 00:00:00
```

For difference convert timestamp to month period by [`Timestamp.to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.to_period.html) and subtract:

```
diff = lastday.to_period('m') - firstday.to_period('m')
print (diff)
12
```

Comment: Thank you, however this seems to give me firstday as: "Timestamp('2017-12-30 00:00:00')". Is there a way to get only the date in clean format, as in "2017-12-30"? The month difference worked nicely.

Comment: @KMFR - for display is possible converting values to `string`s like `print (firstday.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`, but not possible use like `firstday = transactions["Date"].iat[0].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` because not possible working with string reperesentation of datetime later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is for you information

```py
firstdayStr = str(firstday[0])
lastdayStr = str(lastday[0])

months = (lastday[0].year - firstday[0].year) * 12 + lastday[0].month - firstday[0].month
```

output

```
2017-12-30 00:00:00  
2018-12-31 00:00:00  
12
```